# Custom trackbar ticks

Tags: winapi, trackbar, common-controls, custom-draw

I'm using the stock [Trackbar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/trackbar-controls) control. I would like to custom draw the ticks.

Here I made an experiment, just trying to draw in the right place:

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
{
    NMHDR* nMhdr = (NMHDR*) lParam;
    NMCUSTOMDRAW* nMcd = (NMCUSTOMDRAW*) lParam;

    if (nMhdr->code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW)
    {
        switch (nMcd->dwDrawStage)
        {
            case CDDS_PREPAINT:
            {
                return CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
            }

            case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
            {
                if (nMcd->dwItemSpec == TBCD_TICS)
                {
                    FillRect(nMcd->hdc, &nMcd->rc, (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH));

                    return CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT;
                }
                else
                {
                    return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
                }

                break;
            }

            default:
            {
                result = CDRF_DODEFAULT;

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    break;
}
```

In my `CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT`, if `dwItemSpec == TBCD_TICS`, then the update rect (`NMCUSTOMDRAW->rc`) is always an empty rect. I checked, and for the other items (`TBCD_CHANNEL` and `TBCD_THUMB`), I get a valid rect and can draw in place of the channel and thumb.

Ok: so what's the point of `TBCD_TICS` if it doesn't give me a rect to draw in?

So maybe I can get the tick positions another way. Well, there's [TBM_GETTICPOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/tbm-getticpos), which seems like it would work. Except the documentation mentions this:

> The positions of the first and last tick marks are not directly available via this message.

So how can I get the first and last tick positions? They do not correspond with the start and end of the channel, the ticks are inset slightly. Perhaps we can calculate the insert from the sides of the channel, but that seems fragile (especially on differently scaled displays).

Comment: Presumably the first and last ticks are inset by half the width of the slider, which you can get from `TBM_GETTHUMBLENGTH` ? Alternatively, are the tics evenly spaced? If so you can just extrapolate the first and last ones from the gap between the others.

Comment: Thanks! While waiting for a response on this I implemented something like your second suggestion (my ticks are evenly spaced, so I just calculated the gaps). But basing this on the width of the thumb is neater.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So how can I get the first and last tick positions?

The old method (XP and older) to get them seems to still work (I just tested on Windows 10) :

```
    RECT rectTrackbar;
    GetClientRect(hWndTB, &rectTrackbar);
    RECT rectThumb;
    SendMessage(hWndTB, TBM_GETTHUMBRECT, 0, (LPARAM)&rectThumb);
    int nThumbWidth = rectThumb.right - rectThumb.left;
    int nXTicFirst = rectTrackbar.left += (nThumbWidth + 2);
    int nXTicLast = rectTrackbar.right -= (nThumbWidth + 2 + 1);
```